# Overriding model save method does not allow assignment of values

Tags: django

I am attempting to override a model's save method and assign a value to the field when the field is saved:

My models.py:

```
def NewInviteCode():
    import secrets
    print(secrets.token_urlsafe(16))


class Invitation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    last_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    num_invitations = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    uniqcode = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.uniqcode:
            self.uniqcode = NewInviteCode()
            print(f"Saved new unique code: {self.uniqcode}")
        if self.num_invitations:
            self.num_invitations = self.num_invitations + 1
        print(f"Sending invitation to {self.email}..")
        SendInviteActual(self.email)
        print(f"Parameters to be saved are: Code:{self.uniqcode} Name: {self.name} Email: {self.email}")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Unfortunately, on my code execution:

```
fktewVPm63tV-YqXxWPNxQ
Saved new unique code: None
Sending invitation to joel@domain.com.
Mail sent
Parameters to be saved are: Code:None Name: joel Email: joel@domain.com
2019-05-26 20:04:48,972 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/sendinvites
```

What's the problem with the following lines of code?

```
if not self.uniqcode:
    self.uniqcode = NewInviteCode()
    print(f"Saved new unique code: {self.uniqcode}")
```

Comment: What does `NewInviteCode` do, it does not *return* anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your `NewInviteCode` does not *return* anything, it only *`print`s* something. If a Python function does not return something explicitly, it returns `None`. You should return a value, like:

```
def NewInviteCode():
    from secrets import token_urlsafe
    return token_urlsafe(16)
```

That being said, you can set a callable as [**`default=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) for field, like:

```
def new_invite_code():
    from secrets import token_urlsafe
    return token_urlsafe(16)

class Invitation(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True)
    last_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    num_invitations = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    uniqcode = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=new_invite_code, blank=True)
```

We here thus do *not* call the function we pass `new_invite_code`, not the result of `new_invite_code`, we thus do *not* write brackets (like <s>`new_invite_code()`</s>).

this makes your models and `safe(..)` function simpler.

> **Note**: according to the [**PEP-8** style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you probably should rename `NewInviteCode` to `new_invite_code`, like I did in the second code fragment.